# "current vertex declaration does not include all the elements required"

Tags: multithreading, xna

"The current vertex declaration does not include all the elements required by the current vertex shader. TextureCoordinate0 is missing."

I get this error when I try to use a spriteFont to draw my FPS on the screen, on the line where I call spriteBatch.End()

My effect doesn't even use texture coordinates. 
But I have found the root of the problem, just not how to fix it.
I have a separate thread that builds the geometry (an LOD algorithm) and somehow this seems to be why I have the problem.
If I make it non-threaded and just update my mesh per frame I don't get an error.
And also if I keep it multithreaded but don't try to draw text on the screen it works fine.
I just can't do both.

To make it even more strange, it actually compiles and runs for a little bit. But always crashes.
I put a Thread.Sleep in the method that builds the mesh so that it happens less often and I saw that the more I make this thread sleep, and the less it gets called, the longer it will run on average before crashing.
If it sleeps for 1000ms it runs for maybe a minute. If it sleeps for 10ms it doesn't even show one frame before crashing. This makes me believe that it has to do with a certain line of code being executed on the mesh building thread at the same time you are drawing text on the screen.

It seems like maybe I have to lock something when drawing the text, but I have no clue.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

My information comes from the presentation "[Understanding XNA Framework Performance](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=16477)" from GDC 2008. It says:

> - GraphicsDevice is somewhat thread-safe
>
>   - Cannot render from more than one thread at a time
>   - Can create resources and `SetData` while another thread renders
> - ContentManager is not thread-safe
>
>   - Ok to have multiple instances, but only one per thread

My guess is that you're breaking one of these rules somewhere. Or you're modifying a buffer that is being used to render without the appropriate locking.